# Application of Correspondence Theorem

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi: G \to (\mathbb{Z}/(15), +) $ be a surjective homomorphism. Identify $\mathbb{Z}/(15) =G/Ker(\phi).$ Could anyone advise me on how to use Correspondence theorem (http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_(Group_Theory)) to show that $G$ has normal subgroups of indices $3$ and $5$ ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You have $G/ker(\phi)\cong\mathbb Z_{15}$. Use [Cauchy's Group Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_Group_Theorem) to the latter group showing that  $\mathbb Z_{15}$ and so $G/ker(\phi)$ has subgroups of order $3$ and $5$. Use this fact that one of that subgroups is of index $3$ wich is the smallest prime dividing $15$ and the $5$-sylow subgroups is naturally normal in $G/ker(\phi)$.

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to use Correspondence theorem instead?

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$